# what does the sysvar PUBKEYs do?

Tags: web3.js, sysvar

can someone explain what is `SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY`, and all the related `PUBKEY` defined in @solana/web3.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A system account. `Sysvars` provide cluster state information such as current `tick height`, `rewards points values`, etc. Programs can access Sysvars via a Sysvar account `(pubkey)` or by querying via a `syscall`.

- **clock**:    This account contains the clock slot, epoch, and leader_schedule_epoch
- **epoch_schedule**:   This account contains the current cluster rent
- **fees**: This account contains the current cluster fees
- **instructions**: This account contains the serialized transaction instructions
- **recent_blockhashes** : recent blockhashes
- **rent**: This account contains the current cluster rent
- **rewards**   DEPRECATED: This sysvar can be removed once the pico-inflation feature is enabled
- **slot_hashes**: named accounts for synthesized data accounts for bank state, etc.
- **slot_history**: named accounts for synthesized data accounts for bank state, etc.
- **stake_history**: named accounts for synthesized data accounts for bank state, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Solana exposes a variety of cluster state data to programs via sysvar accounts.

It's an address to an account on chain that contains the rental rate. These are static values.

Let's look at the [account data](https://explorer.solana.com/address/SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111):

```
{
   "data":{
      "parsed":{
         "info":{
            "burnPercent":100,
            "exemptionThreshold":2.0,
            "lamportsPerByteYear":"3480"
         },
         "type":"rent"
      },
      "program":"sysvar",
      "space":17
   },
   "executable":false,
   "lamports":1009200,
   "owner":"Sysvar1111111111111111111111111111111111111",
   "rentEpoch":337
}
```

This can be used to calculate rent exemption on chain.

Example: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/cc2739fce1/token-lending/program/src/processor.rs#L1716